# Connect Field and TimebasedPartitioner

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to append a field name to my S3 bucket name while writing files using Kafka S3 connect with TimeBasedPartioner . At the moment the bucket names are like year=YYYY/month=MM/day=dd/hour=HH I want to make it as fieldname=fieldvalue/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=dd/hour=HH . My idea here is to improve parquet query performance by passing fieldname param.

Answer (score 0):

That partitioner doesn't exist out of the box. [There is an open PR for it](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/pull/73/files), which you could separately package as a JAR and add to the classpath, if you are able